# Gmail label colors via API?

Tags: api, gmail

Android client of Gmail uses labels which are exactly as my labels in Gmail web interface. When I started looking for API support, I wasn't able to find any.
Both 
[IMAP extensions](http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/imap/#x-gm-labels) and
[Email API: labels](http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/email_settings/developers_guide_protocol.html#GA_email_label_examples) doesn't provide answer on how do they manage colors through API.

How can I get label colors from gmail via any programming language?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware color isn't one of the attributes that can be set/received.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's this: https://developers.google.com/gmail/android/ as an Android API, so if you're developing for android, this should help you. Otherwise, you might try checking what the labels uri resolves to and try accessing that from your app code.

Or download the android emulator and run gmail on it while running a network sniffer, and see what comes down the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

With this:

```
 GmailContract.Labels.LabelCanonicalName.BACKGROUND_COLOR
```

You can get the background color of the label, in hex format 0xAARRGGBB

i.e:

```
labelsCursor.getString(
                 labelsCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                        GmailContract.Labels.LabelCanonicalName.BACKGROUND_COLOR
                             )
            )
```